# Cannot edit Windows Phone app "Display name"

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app and wanted to change its display name in phone menu. It is done in the Package.appxmanifest file, but when I change it, phone repeatedly shows the old project name.

When I tried to edit Package.appxmanifest file in editor, it showed old display name in the "Display name" node, but after changing it here the problem is still here.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Properties folder, there's a WMAppManifest.xml file in which you have to change the display name.

Read the article: [Prepare your Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app for publishing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655122%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh my, I am dumb. Thanks. I thought this file existen only for 8.0.